# Корень слова «персонаж»

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Какой корень в слове *персонаж*?

Answer (score 11):

Корень "персон", суффикс "аж".  Однокоренное - персона.

Comment: Пусть нас поправит кто-то, знающий словообразование во французском языке, откуда и заимствовано это слово.Свою версию публикую ниже в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Слово **персонаж** целиком заимствовано из французского языка. А там, в свою очередь, произведено по правилам французского языка от латинского **persona** - личность, и выглядит как **personnage**. Стало быть и корень его в русском языке - "**персонаж**".

Comment: Я бы тоже так ответила. Да заглянула в словарь. А там - с суффиксом.